# Image Quality Assessment Algorithms

Tags: deep-learning, generative-models, image-preprocessing, image

I am working on super resolution projects using Generative Adversarial Networks. I need to validate the generated image whether they are close to original one. I already worked with SSIM and PSNR. is there any recent algorithms to compare two images?